# How to modify with a CRUD (laravel-php-resource)

Tags: php, laravel, resources

I am doing a CRUD on race drivers from a database. I have a problem when I modify a driver. To explain, when I try to modify it, the modification does not happen.

My view page to edit a driver :

```
@section('monBody')
    <h1>Les pilotes</h1>
    <br />
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="column"> 
    {{-- {{var_dump($lesCircuits)}} --}}
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
        <thead>
            <td>Prenom</td>
            <td>Nom</td>
            <td>Numero</td>
            <td>NbPoint</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <br />
    @foreach ($lesPilotes as $unPilote)
    <tr>
        {{-- <a href="{{route('pilote.edit',$unPilote->id)}}">{{$unPilote->Id}}</a>--}}
        <td>{{$unPilote->Prenom.""}}</td>
        <td>{{$unPilote->Nom}}</td>
        <td>{{$unPilote->Numero}}</td>
        <td>{{$unPilote->NbPoint.""}}</td>
        <td>

            <a href="{{route('piloteFinal.edit', $unPilote->Id)}}"><button>Modifier</button>
        </td>
</a>
```

My view update for modify the selected driver :

```
@section('monBody')
    <h1>Modifier un pilote</h1>
    <br />
    <form action="{{route('piloteFinal.update', $monPiloteFinal->Id)}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <input type="text" id="updateNomPilote" name="updateNomPilote" placeholder="Prenom" value="{{$monPiloteFinal->Prenom}}">
    <input type="text" id="updatePrenomPilote" name="updatePrenomPilote" placeholder="Prénom" value="{{$monPiloteFinal->Nom}}">
    <input type="text" id="updateNumeroPilote" name="updateNumeroPilote" placeholder="Numéro" value="{{$monPiloteFinal->Numero}}">
    <input type="text" id="updateNbPointPilote" name="updateNbPointPilote" placeholder="Points" value="{{$monPiloteFinal->NbPoint}}">

    {{-- <button type="submit">Modifier</button> --}}
    <input class="" type="submit" value="Valider">
</form>

<br>

@endsection
```

my controller which contains my edit function to go to the update view when the user selects the edit button of the selected driver

my edit function

```
   */
    public function edit(PiloteFinal $piloteFinal)     // fonction permettant d'envoyer au formulaire d'update
    {
        //dd($piloteFinal);
        return view('updatePilote', ['monPiloteFinal'=>$piloteFinal]);
    
    }
```

Update function

```
  public function update(UpdatePiloteFinalRequest $request, PiloteFinal $piloteFinal) // fonction permettant l'update en bdd
    {
        $updateLastnamePilote=$request->input('updateNomPilote');
        $piloteFinal->Nom=$updateLastnamePilote;
        $updateFirstnamePilote=$request->input('updatePrenomPilote');
        $updateNumPilote=$request->input('updateNumeroPilote');
        $updateNbPointsPilote=$request->input('updateNbPointPilote');
        $piloteFinal->Nom=$updateLastnamePilote;
        $piloteFinal->Prenom=$updateFirstnamePilote;
        $piloteFinal->Numero=$updateNumPilote;
        $piloteFinal->NbPoint=$updateNbPointsPilote;
        $piloteFinal->save(); // permet de save en bdd
        return $this->index();  // renvoie à la fonction index, soit la view initiale
    }
```

Models

```
class PiloteFinal extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'Pilote';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'Prenom',
        'Nom',
        'Numero',
        'NbPoint',
    ];
}
```

route I use

```
Route::resource('piloteFinal', PiloteFinalController::class);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting into the update method and not being blocked by the request validation? You can check it by using `Log::info(__FUNCTION__);` at the top of your update function, then checking the log in `storage/logs`. Also watch the Network tab of your browser's developer console when you submit the form to see what the status is on the request.

Comment: Please add more information about routes. You are using PUT method when send request. But it is not clear which is your routes used,

Comment: pls share with us dd($request->all()); also show your model

Comment: I'm doing this right now